# Running a same batch file again every 30 minutes

Tags: windows, batch, counter

I have a batch file which is just a simple batch file. You can take any example. 
How can I keep the batch file running in a loop from start to end again and again, till the specified time is met or the counter is met?

Comment: This could be a possible solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958896/how-to-run-a-batch-file-over-a-period-of-time-repeatedly-scheduling-a-task][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958896/how-to-run-a-batch-file-over-a-period-of-time-repeatedly-scheduling-a-task

Answer (score 0):

If you're on [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) or higher, here is something that may do what you want. For example, this batch file runs a process up to 11 executions, or until 04:17, whichever comes first, waiting one second between each process (to not peg the CPU--if you have file processing you may not need this, or you may actually want to peg the CPU):

```
@echo off
echo Starting Batch...
REM Use 'setlocal' so that we can use an environment variable without it leaking out to the caller.
setlocal

REM Initialize the counter to zero
set counter=0
:AGAIN

REM Increment the counter
set /A counter+=1
echo Processing loop %counter%...

REM Wait for one second so as not to peg the CPU
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK>nul

REM Check the counter to see if we've done enough iterations--bail out if we have
if '%counter%'=='11' goto END

REM Check the time to see if the target time has been reached--if not go back and process again
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('time /T') DO IF NOT '%%A'=='04:17' goto AGAIN

:END

REM End the local processing and go back to the main environment
endlocal
```